# Iceweasel (on Debian) ignoring userChrome.css

Tags: firefox, debian, css, iceweasel

I have installed IceWeasel on Debian

What i'am trying to do is to hide the status popup on the left bottom corner:

[image]

I created `userChrome.css` under `/etc/iceweasel/profile/chrome/` and under `/home/debian/.mozilla/firefox/XXXX.default-XXX/chrome` and copied the following lines into it:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul")
#statusbar-display { display:none !important; }
```

I think i have it done correctly but the messages still pops up.
Someone have an Idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use `statuspanel { display:none!important; }` instead of `#statusbar-display { display:none !important; }`...